# How to capture the first digit while converting a decimal number to binary digit using naive recursion?

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to convert a decimal number to a binary digit in the below way using recursion.

```
def getbin(x: int, s: str):
    if int(x/2) > 0:
        y = int(x/2)
        s += str(y % 2)
        print(f'int(x/2): {int(x/2)}, y: {y}, st: {s}')
        getbin(y, s)
    elif int(x/2) == 1:
        s += '11'
        return s


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(getbin(28, ''))
```

But when I call this, I can see in the output that the first digit of the binary number is not getting captured.
I ran two test cases:

For the number 28, the expected output should be `00111` but the output is `0111`:
[image]

For the number 5, the output should be 101 but the output is `01`
[image]

Could anyone let me know what is the mistake I am making here and how can I correct it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are testing against `x/2` instead of testing against `x`. Thus you lose the most significant bit of the result. Try something like this:

```py
def getbin(x: int, s: str):
    s += str(x % 2)
    y = x // 2
    if y > 0:
        return getbin(y, s)
    return s
```

Note also that you need to reverse the result of `getbin` to get the correct binary string.